# Create/Access a ClearCase view (Snapshot or Dynamic) without local admin privileges

Tags: version-control, clearcase

In our current environment all the users who would like to access ClearCase will require local administrative rights and i'm looking into the options to remove the local admin privs constraint so that all the users should be able to access if they are part of clearcase domain groups like CCUsers.

Answer (score 0):

Local admin privilege should only be required for installing ClearCase, especially when it comes to the MVFS (MultiView FileSystem) part.

But it is also used for launching ClearCase services. Without a privilege elevation, you would see:

```
C:\>net start albd
System error 5 has occurred.
Access is denied.

From Windows Services
Unable to open service Albd for writing on Local Computer
Error 5: Access is denied.
```

First, check if you can set those services as "Automatic": they should be started during Windows Startup, even if the user is *not* an administrator.

[This thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014580210) recommends:

> Click on `Atria Location Broker service` and select `Properties`.
>   On the `General` tab, "`Startup type`" should be "`Automatic`".
>   On the `Log On` tab, select the radio button to Log on as "`This account`" and enter the ALBD user account and password that you should have already setup (e.g. `your-domain\clearcase_albd`). If you do this properly, the Atria Location Broker service should start automatically for any user.

See also "[Troubleshooting ALBD startup failures on Microsoft Windows](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21177467)".

Comment: i verified on the server and these settings are already in place.